# Auto fit tag clouds in a div

Tags: css, tag-cloud, fittextjs

I have some tag clouds placed within a div. For each tag cloud there is a thumbs down icon and I used sliding tag css from http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/sliding-tags

If a tag cloud is greater than 80px, it does not fit inside that div. I used word wrap and also fittext plugin from jquery but I could not manage to make it work. Could you suggest what could be the possible solution for it?

I have created fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/aexqoe8n/1/

In Js side :

```
resultDiv = document.getElementById('tokenCloudResultDiv');
resultDiv.innerHTML = '';
resultDiv .innerHTML="<ul  class='tags blue' style='list-style-type: none;padding:5px;'>";
for (i in json) {
    addToken(resultDiv, i, json[i]);
}
resultDiv.innerHTML=resultDiv.innerHTML+"</ul>";

function addToken(target, key, result) {
    var str;
    var weight;

    if(result['tagWeight']>80)
        $("#tokenCloudResultDiv").fitText(1.2);

    weight= "style='font-size: " + result['tagWeight']  + "px;'";
    if(addedAutomatically)
    str = "<li><div><a " + weight + " >" + result['tagName'] +"</a><span   class='thumbsDownIcon' id ='" + tagId + "' style='display:block;cursor:pointer;' ></span></div></li>";
    target.innerHTML += str;
}
```

Comment: I tried by assigning an id to each a element and then call fitText() and it worked in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aexqoe8n/2/

Comment: But when i tried on my project, i get an error:Could not load the source for js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js.
Error: Request failed with status code = 2152398875 in onStopRequest handler for url = ..path to this folder/js//lib/jquery-1.10.2.js. DO you have idea what does it mean?